# gcc/ld does not follow symbolic linked files when linking

Tags: gcc, ubuntu

I'm currently switch from ubuntu 11.04 (gcc 4.5) to ubuntu 12.04 (but I have the same problem with ubuntu 11.10 too, gcc 4.6) and am not able to compile some of my projects anymore.

I have a library, lets call it liba, which I build myself so I get

```
liba.so.0.0.1 (real library)
liba.so.0  -> liba.so.0.0.1 (symbolic link)
liba.so    -> liba.so.0.0.1 (symbolic link)
```

but when I try to build a program using liba with:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -la
```

I get an error that my library can not be found:

```
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -la
```

On the other hand if I delete liba.so and rename liba.so.0.0.1 to liba.so everything works fine. Alternatively calling gcc with the full shared library its file name works find:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -l:liba.so.0.0.1
```

Unfortunately due to versioning reasons in my build system these two solutions are not desirable to me.

Ideas?

EDIT: nevermind I found the problem is with 'new' vmware not supporting symlinks in shared folders. USing NFS now and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the location where `liba` lives is mentioned in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig`. Alternativly you can give the search path with `-Lpath`.